# jquery click() not triggering on button

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to have a button clicked `onload` of a page, for a default event,
but neither `click()` nor `trigger("click")` seem to be working.

Here is a sample:

https://jsfiddle.net/kneidels/Lras6fcy/

```js
$("#getAttendanceRep").click();

$("#getAttendanceRep").click(function() {
  alert('clicked');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="datepicker form-control" value="2/2/2019" name="date" id="date">
<input type="button" id="getAttendanceRep" value="Display Slots" class="btn" />
```

What am I getting wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're triggering the click *before* you've attached the handler.

Swap them around for your expected result:

```js
$("#getAttendanceRep").click(function() {
    alert('clicked');
});

$("#getAttendanceRep").click();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="datepicker form-control" value="2/2/2019" name="date" id="date">
<input type="button" id="getAttendanceRep" value="Display Slots" class="btn" />
```

Or simply, [as suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59394938/jquery-click-not-triggering-on-button#comment104979223_59394990):

```
$("#getAttendanceRep").click(function() { /* ... */ }).click();
```

Comment: ... or just append `.click()` at the end of the chain.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález ... another possibility, yes.

Comment: Thank you. I cannot add the `click()` at the end of the chain, because I call this function at various times on the page. also - I did not know that the function had to exist before calling it - would have thought (and was sure) it would run as long as it exists somewhere on the page.

Comment: @kneidels putting `.click()` on the end will not keep the clicking of the element by the user from working.  All `click()` on the end does is force it to execute at least once.  As far as the element having to exist on the page, it does have to exist.  If, in the source code, the script is above the element it will attempt to target, the code will run before the elements exist.  In that case it becomes necessary to either move the script after the elements it will target, or put the logic in a document ready or a load event handler.

Comment: The lattter two options being available to delay the execution of the logic until the document is loaded into the DOM, or all resources (images, videos, etc) are loaded, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

the `click` event doesn't exist when you call it, so you need to call him after you create the `click` event.
Or a better way will be to attach the event to the end of the chain, like this:

```
$("#getAttendanceRep").click(function(){
 alert('clicked');
}).click();
```

Comment: Sorry, other people answered the same answers before I saw them.

Answer (score 0):

To have the button click event fire after the page has loaded you should wrap it with a document ready check like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#getAttendanceRep").click(function () {
        alert('clicked');
    });

    $("#getAttendanceRep").click();
});
```

[Updated sample](https://jsfiddle.net/9d6cgjLe/)

Comment: If the document isn't ready when you do the binding, how's that going to work?  If the binding is successful outside of a document ready, the click will definitely also be available.

Comment: You're ignoring the point.  The original issue demonstrated was that the invocation of `click()` happened before the binding.  The fix of that was to simply put the `click()` invocation after the binding.  Wheither or not the user has/had an issue with the element being available to be selected or not had not been demonstrated.  Futhermore my point remains.  If the document may not be ready yet, **both** the binding and the invocation would need to be in the document ready

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/btgk16vL/  Without the binding being in the document ready, if the script is before the elements being targeted, it will not work.